# How to Filter Unique data in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have data in azure Insights saved in custom events formats. These custom events has data like  Name , Email, Title
There can be multiple rows with the same email. 
Now I want data to be grouped by email so that I can get Name, Email, Title. means need to fetch data of unique emails.

I tries to use like

```
customEvents
| summarize by tostring(customDimensions["email"])
```

But its returning me only email . Now how I can get another columns?
even

```
| project customDimensions["email"], customDimensions["name"] 
,customDimensions["title"]
```

not working

I have three columns in azure insights. Customdata has a string value column and and a json string of data stored in it.

```
ID TimeStamp          Customdata    
1   21-12-2018       "{email:"xyz@xyz.com", name:"james",title: "Dev"}"

1   21-12-2018       "{email:"abc@abc.com", name:"Will",title: "Tester"}"

1   21-12-2018       "{email:"xyz@xyz.com", name:"james",title: "Dev"}"
1   21-12-2018       "{email:"xyz@xyz.com", name:"Happy",title:"Developer"}"
1   21-12-2018       "{email:"xyz@xyz.com", name:"JOhn",title: "Developer"}"
```

Now I need a query that can return

```
Email          Name   Title  CountOfRecords

xyz@xyz.com    James   Dev      2 
abc@abc.com    Will   Tester    1
```

help me here to write the query.

Comment: Does the answer below work for you? If you have more question, please let me know. If it works for you, could you please mark it as answer? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below(please point me out if I misunderstand you):

**data source like below:**

[image]

**The query(please adjust the where sentence as per your need):**

```
customEvents
| where timestamp >ago(1d)
| where name == "w1" 
| summarize CountOfRecords = count() by Email = tostring(customDimensions["email"]), Name=tostring(customDimensions["name"]),Title=tostring(customDimensions["title"])
```

**The test result:**

[image]